# PHP: How should do mail merge with openoffice?

Tags: java, php, merge, openoffice.org, mailmerge

I have question about integrate Open office with PHP. I want make mail merge from PHP. 
Do you have any idea what should exaclly I do with this?

There any options with java's calling from php?

Comment: sound overcomplicated, why not using the mail function of PHP and create the mail in plain PHP?

Comment: @RageZ: "Mail merge" in the office packages can be used for snail-mail as well (in fact, that was its original purpose).

Comment: Did you try any of the options listed in The Fine Manual? http://php.net/manual/en/intro.java.php

Comment: I want do this by the openoffice template, so I can't do this by the mail functions.

Comment: @Piskvor in manual I can read this `This extension is considered unmaintained and dead.`, so that can work unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write jar file - based on iText, in Java and I call it from PHP comand line, works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) to easily build your mail merge under PHP. OpenTBS is a PHP class which can build real ODT files, and also any OpenOffice and Ms Office documents using templates. You just design the template with OpenOffice and then merge it with the data under PHP and you have a new ODT directly for download, or as a files saved on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean "Java's calling from PHP", but you could call the command line of [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/) depending on your performance requirements.

Hope that helps.